# Select child controls in custom usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, custom-controls, design-time

I am building an application that can handle modules from third parties.

All modules must have the same look and feel, therefor I've created a .dll for convenience.

**Problem** When using my custom usercontrol template *ModuleChrome*, developers can't select the child containers called *ToolBar* & *Body* and their respective children. This is really inconvenient since when selecting the child element in designer, the whole usercontrol (*ModuleChrome*) is selected.

**Question** How do I make the controls inside *ToolBar* & *Body* selectable in designer?

The class for ModuleChrome

```
public class ModuleChrome : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolBarProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ToolBar", typeof(object), typeof(ModuleChrome), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Body", typeof(object), typeof(ModuleChrome), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object ToolBar
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ToolBarProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolBarProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Body
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(BodyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BodyProperty, value); }
    }

    static ModuleChrome()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ModuleChrome), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ModuleChrome)));
    }
}
```

And its corresponding style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ModuleChrome}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ModuleChrome}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!--Main Content-->
                    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Body}"/>
                    </ContentControl>

                    <!--Toolbar-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
                        <Grid.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="4" Opacity="0.5"/>
                        </Grid.Effect>
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding ToolBar}"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And usage

```
<chrome:ModuleChrome ....
    ....
    ....
    xmlns:chrome="....">


<chrome:ModuleChrome.ToolBar>
        <Grid Background="White"/>
    </chrome:ModuleChrome.ToolBar>

    <chrome:ModuleChrome.Body>
        <Grid Background="White"/>
    </chrome:ModuleChrome.Body>

</chrome:ModuleChrome>
```

I've searched the web for an solution, but obviously couldn't find it. Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

I've gotten this to work in a single usercontrol

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MultiChildDemo : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ToolBarProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "ToolBar",
        typeof(UIElementCollection),
        typeof(MultiChildDemo),
        new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey BodyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "Body",
        typeof(UIElementCollection),
        typeof(MultiChildDemo),
        new PropertyMetadata());


    public UIElementCollection ToolBar
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ToolBarProperty.DependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolBarProperty, value); }
    }

    public UIElementCollection Body
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(BodyProperty.DependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BodyProperty, value); }
    }

    public MultiChildDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToolBar = gridToolBar.Children;
        Body = gridBody.Children;
    }
}
```

And xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="gridBody"/>

    <Grid x:Name="gridToolBar" Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="4" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Problem with this approach**

This is in a single usercontrol, I could use it in every module(usercontrol), but I need to transfer this functionality to my CustomControl, since UserControls doesnt allow for naming the content when using it as a template.

*If we find an solution I will update with answer.*